# Spring MVC 2.5 Exception Handling display error pop up same page

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, exception, popup

I am looking for the way to manage the checked and non-checked Exceptions in the MVC Spring project. And finally display a pop up with the message error.

I know how to redirect the flow toward a error page with SimpleMappingExceptionResolver. But I need to remain in the same page and just display the pop up with jquery.

Thanks

Comment: I need a Centralized Exception Handling. Some samples with these techs¿?

Comment: Community, if you think that this question is useful and it deserves to be resolved, please VOTE IT, and we can achieve that other experts help us soon

Comment: Have you got a response about this issue? I'm with same problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exception(in your resolver for example) and add error message to the users session. Than you create controller, which take message from users session and return it in the responce.
On the client side you poll this controller and shows message.